# How Do I Sort By The Newest Database Entry In PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I my webpage has it so you can make a post and then people can reply to it so it has a postId that increments by one for identifying each new thread and a replyId that increments one to identify each reply. Right now on the navigator I have it so the highest (or newest) post is shown at the top and going down as they get older with

```
<?php
$thread1TitleR = "SELECT * FROM newThread ORDER BY postId DESC";
$thread1Title = mysqli_query($con, $thread1TitleR);
if ($thread1Title) {
        while ($row = $thread1Title->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<a href='" . $row['postId'] . ".php'>" . $row['thread'] . "</a>" . "<br/><br/>";
        }
}
?>
```

But I want to make it so the thread with the newest user input is at the top going down. So for example I want it so a brand new thread that has just been created is at the top or if an old thread with no replies it goes to the top or if its a old thread with a lot of replies if someone replies to it it will go back up to the top. Basically I want it to go by latest user input. If this does not make sense or if you have any questions please ask in the comments I have been trying to figure this out for awhile.

When I run `show create table newThread;` it returns `` Array ( [Table] => newThread [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `newThread` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `thread` text NOT NULL, `threadText` text NOT NULL, `name` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ) ``
some of that is not related and when simplifying the code to where it didn't matter got rid of it

When I run `show create table reply` it returns `` ( [Table] => reply [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `reply` ( `replyId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `threadId` int(11) NOT NULL, `reply` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`replyId`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ) ``  I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a table related with replies?

Comment: @Jsowa That reverses it

Comment: @Cid Yes and it has the same format as the thread table except its replyId and reply instead of postId and thread

Comment: can you show us the structures of both tables with sample data? a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) would be great

Comment: @Cid I used graphical MySQL environment so I don't actually know how I did it, I click the buttons and it does stuff. But the table is called reply and it has 3 columns (I forgot to mention one when simplifying the code) it has `replyId` which auto increments like postId of the newThread table. It has `threadId` which is tethered to the Id of what thread is being replied to to identify where they belong. And theres `reply` which is just the text of what the reply is.

Comment: Where is `replyid` stored?

Comment: Run `mysqli_query($con, 'show create table newThread')` and same for `reply`. Then add output to the question.

Comment: @user3783243 Okay I did. Did I get all the info needed?

Comment: The reason that Cid asked for a fiddle is because that instantly sets up a sandbox environment for volunteers to trial their advice on.  Having realistic data to play with is part of creating a [mcve].  After providing sample data, we need to know your exact desired output/resultset.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to first get the database sorted. Currently you are not using foreign keys and therefor the database does not know that threadId in reply corresponds to the id of newThread, meaning you can get invalid data and more.

As to sorting out depending on the newest reply,

```
SELECT 
    newThread.id, 
    newThread.thread,
    newThread.threadText,
    newThread.name
FROM newThread 
LEFT JOIN reply on newThread.id = reply.threadId
JOIN (SELECT reply.threadId, 
      MAX(reply.replyId) replyId 
      FROM reply 
      GROUP BY reply.threadId) t1
ON reply.threadId = t1.threadId AND reply.replyId = t1.replyId
Order By reply.replyId DESC
```

And so inside php

```
<?php
$thread1TitleR = "SELECT 
    newThread.id, 
    newThread.thread,
    newThread.threadText,
    newThread.name
FROM newThread 
LEFT JOIN reply on newThread.id = reply.threadId
JOIN (SELECT reply.threadId, 
      MAX(reply.replyId) replyId 
      FROM reply 
      GROUP BY reply.threadId) t1
ON reply.threadId = t1.threadId AND reply.replyId = t1.replyId
Order By reply.replyId DESC";
$thread1Title = mysqli_query($con, $thread1TitleR);
if ($thread1Title) {
        while ($row = $thread1Title->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<a href='" . $row['postId'] . ".php'>" . $row['thread'] . "</a>" . "<br/><br/>";
        }
}
?>
```

This should get you a list of all the topics with the newest/highest reply id to them. Might not be the most efficient method, but it works.

Edit, quickly inversed the order so the newest is on top.

Comment: It seems to be that it only shows up on the navigator after it has a reply. How can I make it show up even if it has no user submitted replies?

Comment: Where would you want those to be? As you are not using a timestamp it will not be able to know which one is older, a reply or a new topic.

Comment: You could add a union to add those that do not have a foreign key, but if you want to also have those that do not have a reply to be in the list you will either have to make the opening in the thread also a reply or add dates and work with those.

Comment: How would I add dates in and work with those?

Comment: Add another column with type timestamp and use that. Timestamp automatically enteres the date and time that a record was made. Then create a query that sorts on that.

Comment: Would you add `newThread.time` under `newThread.name` and then `reply.time` under `reply.threadId` and then `Order By newThread.time DESC, reply.time DESC";`?